# Is there a way to bypass the "File in Use" dialogue when opening an existing Word Doc?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to open a word document from excel, and it keeps popping up the dialogue "doc is locked for editing by user... Do you want to: Open a read only file etc." When I set ReadOnly to True and I run the VBA, the little circle spins for a minute and nothing happens. I've also tried setting display alerts to false as well, but this message box ignores this handler for some reason.

```
Sub PreClear()

Dim CS As Workbook
Dim wrd As Word.Application
Dim pc As Word.Document


Set CS = ThisWorkbook

Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set pc = wrd.Documents.Open(Filename:="filepath.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
  

End Sub
```

Comment: Untested, but try `wrd.DisplayAlerts = 0` before attempting `Set pc = ...`

Comment: I'm still running into the same issue @BigBen. When I add this and delete ReadOnly:=True, nothing runs. When I leave ReadOnly:=True, I still get the dialogue box.